# How to Access Mapped Network Drive on Windows from the Ubuntu app?

Tags: ubuntu, python, mapped-drive

I use a Windows 10 computer and I have installed the Ubuntu app from the Microsoft store. I have a mapped network drive on my Windows computer that I would like to access from within the Ubuntu app. How do I do this?

I am able to find folders on my Windows computer in the Ubuntu app by typing cd /mnt/c/Users/Name/Desktop, for example, but I am not sure how to find the mapped network drive from within the Ubuntu app or if this is even possible. I have very large files on the mapped network drive that I would like to use as inputs for a python program on my computer, but I am not sure if it is possible to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. map the network drive on Windows, e.g. as drive T:
2. start the WSL2 system
3. create a mount point

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/t
```

4. mount the mapped network drive

```
sudo mount -t drvfs T: /mnt/t
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this permanent? When I close out of the WSL2 terminal the drive is no longer mounted and I have to reinput the second command each time

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dZEAQwXzTsA

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).